# Python, while loop stops after one iteration

Tags: python, debugging, while-loop, iteration, break

When the program receives input for "cubes", I want to first check if the maximum value is on one end of the sequence. If yes, delete the max value, if not, exit and print no. As long as 'd' is not empty, keep on looping, till 'd' is empty. Then print yes, or exit the program in one of the loops.

I can input 'T' number of test sequences.
Suppose I give a sequence [4, 3 ,1, 3 ,4]. It only does one iteration, but it should keep on and delete 4, 3, 3, 1. Thank you for help! I am kind of not very experienced.

```
from collections import deque
T=int(input())#number of test cases

for i in range(T):
    n=int(input())
    cubes=map(int, input().split())
    d=deque(cubes)       
    while len(d)!=0:
        a=max(d)
        if d.index(a)==0 or d.index(a)==-1:
            d.remove(a)
        else:
            break
            
     if len(d)==0:
         print('yes')
     else:
         print ('no')
```

Comment: Please provide the *actual* input you provide, as opposed to what it represents.  Also note that this will *never* print `No`, since it comes immediately after  a `break` but it still inside the `else`.

Comment: yes, yes you are right, I changed the code, you can read it now in the question. thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I think you compare the wrong indexes here:

```
if d.index(a)==0 or d.index(a)==-1:
```

If element is the last, index returns `len(d) - 1`, not `-1`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.index

You should write something like:

```
if d.index(a) == 0 or d.index(a) == len(d)-1:
```

Comment: @laughter, you should also pay attention to the comment under the question and swap `break` and `print('No')`

Comment: hallelujah, it works now, thank you , I probably will never find out the reason myself; thank you !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

While reading your code, I noticed :

```
cubes=map(int, input().split())
```

`input()` imports your input as a string, while `String#split` with no argument splits using  *space*.

So if you provide the string `[4, 3 ,1, 3 ,4]`, you get the following array:

```
['[4,', '3', ',1,', '3', ',4]']
```

Try `4 3 1 3 4` as input?

Comment: I used deque object, just changed my text, imported deque